# MATLAB How to make `eigs` work correctly or alternative to `eigs` for sparse matrix

Tags: matlab

`eigs(A,k,'sm')` returns the k smallest magnitude eigenvalues.  However, it gives a warning that not all eigenvalues converge and cannot give `k` of the smallest eigenvalues.

On the other hand, using `eig(full(A))`, performing sorting myself and extracting the smallest `k` of the eigenvalues does give me the same answer.

By searching over the internet for a long time, I have heard a lot of negative comments about `eigs`. However, since my matrix `A` is sparse and large. `eigs` seems to be the best way to go in speed, is there any way I can make `eigs(A,k,'sm')` right and output the correct eigenvalues I look for. Or is there another more reliable and faster numerical scheme for finding eigenvalues of sparse matrix?

Comment: Are you sure that `eig` gives the correct eigenvalues? Isn't your matrix very ill-conditioned?

Comment: @Andras Deak actually I am not sure of that. What can I do if `eig` does not give correct eigenvalues and my matrix is very ill-conditioned?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I'm afraid I can't tell you that. But I suggest that you check the `cond()` (approximate condition number) of your matrix, and possibly its determinant (although the latter is less informative).

Comment: There's also this note in the [documentation of `eigs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html#moreabout): "*If eigs fails to converge for a given matrix, increase the number of Lanczos basis vectors by increasing the value of opts.p. As secondary options, adjusting the maximum number of iterations, opts.maxit, and the convergence tolerance, opts.tol, can also help with convergence behavior.*"

Comment: alright thanks for that